# Unable to set image to the imageview dynamically from web

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, nsdata

I'm using the following piece of code to download image from web and add it to array.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:
                        [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                         [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://tcpm.mrlazyinc.com/files/users/themafia/te/beauty/02.jpg"]]];

    recipePhotos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:myImage, @"2.png", @"3.png", @"4.png", @"5.png", @"6.png", @"6.png", @"8.png", @"9.png", @"10.png", nil];
});
```

I'm setting the image on to the ui using the following code,

```
UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipePhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

During runtime, image is downloaded from the web is not displayed. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

what u are doing is using [UIImage imageNamed: ]
but this will access the object of array recipePhotos and the string in each object will be returned.so u dont have images with those  names.
Since the object stored in array is an image u should try this

so try doing

`recipeImageView.image = [recipePhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`

or

`recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[recipePhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`

Comment: only for the first image the rest u need to load with imageNamed: since they are images which u acces from ur project file.

Answer (score 0):

In the array recipePhotos only the first index contains proper `UIImage` as it contains full path that is `"http://tcpm.mrlazyinc.com/files/users/themafia/te/beauty/02.jpg"` (`myImage`) and other than that only strings without the file path that is `http://tcpm.mrlazyinc.com/files/users/themafia/te/beauty/`

```
recipePhotos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:myImage, @"2.png", @"3.png", @"4.png", @"5.png", @"6.png", @"6.png", @"8.png", @"9.png", @"10.png", nil];
```

});

Try to `NSLog` the array `recipePhotos`

Comment: it prints some numbers inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use SDWebImage Class to set image to the imageview dynamically from web

Import following file to your header file.

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

after importing file try following code.

```
[self.imgLogo sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.dictTemp valueForKey:@"camp_image"]]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"]];
```

**Download library from below link :-**

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage